# JetBrains IDE - Is it possible to create an alias for existing command?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I had a simple task to convert inherited file to Unix-style line endings. Not a very frequent task that I often perform.

[image]

First idea was to just type "line ending" in *Enter action or option name* tool window but I didn't know that JetBrains refer to it as "line separator" instead:

[image]

Is it possible to add this alias somewhere in configuration so that this command could be called as "line ending" as well?

Please note, "line ending/separator" is just an example because I remember there were other cases like this. Jetbrains IDE have tons of command and sometimes I'm not good at instantly recalling the actual option/command name for rare commands.

Comment: Finding something you don't know their name for is a real mess in intellij. I don't think there is a possibility - the only thing I'm doing is to type as few characters as possible and scroll through the list...

Comment: Good suggestion baao, it's hard to find a feature if you don't now the name indeed. Note that IntelliJ is really good at finding matches. You can just type the first letter of a class/action etc. and it will show matching results. Nearly works in every input field :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign "abbreviations" to actions in IntelliJ.
Although "Line ending" is not really an abbreviation, but it may do the trick.

To assign an abbreviation for any given action, look it up in preferences (settings) -> keymap
right click on the action of your choice and select `add abbreviation`.
Now suppose you give the `line separator` the abbreviation `line ending` you can search for the action by typing "line ending" instead and it will pop up.

(although in my context I had to search for disabled actions) but thats maybe a project setting...

Comment: ">Although "Line ending" is not really an abbreviation, but it may do the trick." I could successfully add an abbreviation for "Line Separators" command. Thank you so much for the tip!